# Error restarting service: Failed to try-restart nscd.service: Unit nscd.service not found

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, startupscript

I am trying to add a `startup script` in my GCP VM Instance to fetch data from a website (web crawler). I wanted to automate the crawling task following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69737208/5920567). So, I added a startup script in my VM instance. The script looks like below:

```
#! /bin/bash

python3 /home/sadmanks/site-spider/src/main.py
```

Then, I wanted to schedule this instance. But when executing this startup script, it doesn't start the program that I want to execute. The log message that I get is following:

```
"Error restarting service: Failed to try-restart nscd.service: Unit nscd.service not found
```

I tried to do this in the browser ssh connection: `sudo service nscd start` outputs:

```
Failed to start nscd.service: Unit nscd.service not found.
```

Does anyone have any idea, how to resolve this issue?

Note: The program runs perfectly when I try to connect the instance with an SSH to my local machine.

Comment: This barely is GCP related, when running faulty scripts. Common sense might suggest to install NSCD.

Comment: Why are you trying to manage the Name Service Cache Daemon? That service is not related to python, web scraping/crawling, etc. Perhaps you are confusing that service with DNS? Make sure you know what your program is doing before running it on public servers.

Comment: Yes, both of you are right. I could ignore those error messages for my task.

Answer (score 1):

The error  "Error restarting service: Failed to try-restart nscd.service: Unit crond.service not found." is just harmless log spam. These error messages show up on every VM on start-up and are expected since systemd services like **crond.service** and **nscd.service** do not exist on COS. So, try updating the version of google-guest-agent service. But as suggested by @John Hanley that service is not related to python, web scraping/crawling, etc. So, make sure you know what the program is doing before running it on public servers.